# Separable equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at this first order separable differential equation, and I am stuck.

Here is the equation:

> $\frac{du}{dt}=u$

I seperated like this:

$ \frac{du}{u}=dt $

Integrated both sides and got:

$ \ln|u|=t+c $

Then I solved for u and got:

$ u=e^{t+c} $

So why does the answer key say $u=ce^t$

Comment: law of exponents. $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$

Comment: One more thing you should keep in mind. $e^{\text{ constant }}=\text{ a positive constant }$

Comment: @randomgirl, the 2nd comment helped a lot!

Comment: Neatness! ' : ) '

Comment: your $u$ seems positive. what are you going to do with $\frac{du}{dt} = u, u(0) = -1?$

Comment: @abel what do you mean?

Comment: when you went from $\ln|u|  = t + c$ to $u = e^{t+c}$ you needed $u = \pm e^{t+C}$ so that you can handle both positive and negative initial conditions.

Comment: @abel, Oh i see! So then shouldn't the answer be u=+/-ce^t ?

Comment: the reason i used $\pm e^{t+c}$ is $e^c$ is always positive. now, if you write $ce^t,$ then there is no need for $\pm ce^t.$

Comment: @abel. Got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are welcome